# DispatcherTimer in MVVM with Prism?

Tags: mvvm, timer, uwp, .net-core, prism

I'm working on a multi-platform MVVM app, and I want to keep the ViewModel platform-agnostic.

I need to make use of `DispatcherTimer` or any other timer. Since the `DispatcherTimer` is not part of .NET Standard/Core, I was wondering if there are better alternatives to use so I can keep the VM clean of plat-specific code (I want it to depend only on .NET Core)?

The way it works is that the ViewModel implements an interface that exposes an event that the View is listening to, and responds to it accordingly.
The timer raises this event upon each tick.

Comment: Do you need said code to run on the UI thread?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I've updated my question.

Comment: Why do you require the view model to raise the event on UI thread? Why not just use the UI thread on the view level? And what is your app targeting? If you are targeting Prism.UWP then you just can use `DispatcherTimer`. If you want to have the view model cross platform, you could use an interface that the consumers of the library would have to implement - something like `IDispatcher` with method `RunOnUiThread(Action action)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option would be to just use classic `Timer`, which does fire on a non-UI thread and then just use `Dispatcher` manually in the consuming view. This is however not that convenient.

Other option would be to provide an interface, that consumers of your library could implement, which would have a method like `RunOnUiThread(Action action)` and which you would just use to make sure the view-specific code runs on the UI thread.

The best solution would probably be to get inspiration in `Prism` itself. For example the `EventAggregator` in the library can publish events on the UI thread - it first captures the current thread's synchronization context (see [here on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Prism/Events/PubSubEvent.cs#L84)):

```
var syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
```

This must be done for example during the View model construction, on the UI thread. And then you can invoke an action on this UI synchronization context even from another thread (see [here on GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2ecbf13ed59b288d8d88446b535780bdc211b6e1/Source/Prism/Events/DispatcherEventSubscription.cs#L33)):

```
syncContext.Post((o) => action(), null);
```

This way you could just use one of the .NET Standard [Timer classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) and from their callback then use the `SynchronizationContext` to run an action on UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I think I'll go with `EventAggregator` and use the .NET Standard `Timer` class to raise the Prism event.

Comment: Yes, event aggregator is a great solution if you are already using Prism. No reinventing the wheel there :-)

Answer (score 1):

The other way you should know about DispatcherTimer is sometimes we may use DispatcherTimer to do something alternately.

We can use `Task.Delay` to replace DispatcherTimer sometimes.

Such as we need to run the code A every 5 seconds.

```
   public async void Foo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // run a every 5 seconds
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            A();
        }
    }

    private void A()
    {

    }
```

And the A will run in the main thread if the main thread calls the Foo and I think you 
 can consider using this method in the framework.

Comment: I'm afraid the timing won't be accurate enough this way. But it's good noting out for the reference.